# Dataloader - AES246 encryption during upload - Check java version for AES256 compatibility?

Tags: data-loader, encryption

One of the key requirement from the business and as per the policy is to encrypt (using AES256) while the data is pushed from the Data Loader (deployed in the local machine) into SFDC (while in transit). Though some of the post on the same topic suggests to use custom webservice to realize this requirement, I had a reference that since dataloader is java application  checking Java version installed for compatibility with AES256 will solves the problem. This would be either be to upgrade the JDK installation or add Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy to the JRE.

Any thoughts on this please? also need advise on how to check if the java version installed is compatible with AES256 and how to install the JCE as told?